# Real closure in PHP <5.3

Tags: php, functional-programming, closures

Is there any way to write real closures in PHP for language versions older than 5.3 (as 5.3 added the `use` keyword for anonymous functions)?

I PHP 5.3+ I can write:

```
function make_adder($x) {
    return function($to) use ($x) {
        return $to + $x;
    };
}
$add5 = make_adder(5);
$add5(100); # => 105
```

How can I use this patterns of defining functions inside functions and the inner functions have access to outer function variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following would work in this simple case:

```
function make_adder($x) {
    return create_function('$to', 'return '.var_export($x, true).' + $to;');
}
$add5 = make_adder(5);
$add5(100); # => 105
```

But that's not a closure in its strict sense.

Comment: Clever use of `var_export` there! :-D

Comment: OK, this works ...but it defeats the whole purpose of closures: clean and readable code (imagine doing this for a  few 10 lines functions...) :(

Comment: You asked for a solution in PHP < 5.3. There is no equivalent of anonymous functions other than `create_function()`.

Comment: ...though it can be used in script to backport 5.3 to 5.2 code automatically

Comment: @NeuronQ: although there are some uses of closures that cannot be done through this method, so the script would need to be able to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: What you're asking for cannot be done in PHP versions older than 5.3. Sorry, but the functionality simply is not available. There aren't even any useful work-arounds (besides using global variables of course).

However, if you are using a version of PHP older than 5.3, I would *strongly* advise you to upgrade.

5.2 was declared end of life two years ago, and has had zero support or security fixes since then -- it is unsupported and insecure.

In addition, that lack of support also extends to operating systems. For most server operating systems, installers for 5.2 and earlier do not exist for current OS versions. This means that if you're running PHP 5.2, it follows that you're likely to also be running an obsolete OS version. This also has security implications.

No sys admin worth his pay would allow his network to run known-insecure software on a publicly-accessible system, so if you haven't upgraded already, you really need to do so now.

If you're using a web hosting company that hasn't upgraded, you should be considering moving your business to a company that cares about the security of their network.

Comment: The question never said anything about needing to host it anywhere or anything. It's just a question about the language.